# R: How to re-concatenate a split string in a data frame

Tags: r, split, concatenation

I created a data frame using the following:

```
Student <- c("John Davis","Angela Williams","Bullwinkle Moose","David Jones",
"Janice Markhammer","Cheryl Cushing","Reuven Ytzrhak","Greg Knox","Joel England",
"Mary Rayburn")
Math <- c(502,600,412,358,495,512,410,625,573,522)
Science <- c(95,99,80,82,75,85,80,95,89,86)
English <- c(25,22,18,15,20,28,15,30,27,18)
student.exam.data <- data.frame(Student,Math,Science,English)
```

I then split "John Davis" via `student.exam.data$Student[1] <- strsplit(as.character(student.exam.data$Student[1]), " ", fixed = FALSE)` into `c("John", "Davis")`.

I'm now attempting to re-concatenate the two characters into a single "John Davis" string. I've tried `paste(student.exam.data$Student[1], collapse = " ")`, `paste(as.vector(student.exam.data$Student[1]), collapse = " ")`, and `toString(student.exam.data$Student[1])`. All three return `"c(\"John\", \"Davis\")"`.

Firstly, why do these return the backslashes, and secondly, what would be the appropriate way to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the line

```
student.exam.data$Student[1] <- strsplit(as.character(student.exam.data$Student[1]), " ", fixed = FALSE)
```

Transforms the first variable in your dataframe into a list ---

```
str(student.exam.data)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Student:List of 10
..$ : chr  "John" "Davis"
..$ : chr "Angela Williams"
..$ : chr "Bullwinkle Moose"
..$ : chr "David Jones"
..$ : chr "Janice Markhammer"
..$ : chr "Cheryl Cushing"
..$ : chr "Reuven Ytzrhak"
..$ : chr "Greg Knox"
..$ : chr "Joel England"
..$ : chr "Mary Rayburn"
$ Math   : num  502 600 412 358 495 512 410 625 573 522
$ Science: num  95 99 80 82 75 85 80 95 89 86
$ English: num  25 22 18 15 20 28 15 30 27 18
```

As such the first element has two values. This works to recombine in the literal sense of answering your question --

```
student.exam.data$Student[1]<-paste(student.exam.data$Student[1][[1]],student.exam.data$Student[1][[2]])
```

What it doesn't do is remedy the fact that your first variable is still a list.

Answer (score 1):

You may find it more convenient to use `tidyr::separate()` and `unite()`.

Example:

```
library(tidyr)

student.exam.data %>% separate(Student, c('first_name','last_name')) -> d2

head(d2,3)
```

returns:

```
  first_name last_name Math Science English
1       John     Davis  502      95      25
2     Angela  Williams  600      99      22
3 Bullwinkle     Moose  412      80      18
```

likewise:

```
d2 %>% unite('full_name', first_name, last_name, sep=' ') -> d3

head(d3, 3)
```

returns:

```
         full_name Math Science English
1       John Davis  502      95      25
2  Angela Williams  600      99      22
3 Bullwinkle Moose  412      80      18
```